# why the limit point is non zero in infinite product? what is the reason for that?

Tags: complex-analysis

If the limit point is zero were permitted any infinite product with one factor 0 would coverge and convergence would no depend on the whole sequence of factors. I couldn't understand this statement.

Comment: Could you give a precise quote of the statement?

Answer (score 0):

Infinite products "converge" when the sum of their logarithms converges. This happens when the limit of the partial products exists and is nonzero. This gives some convenient properties that you do not get otherwise.

Comment: Thanks to ans me.but i ask what is the reason for it must nonzero. Plz

Comment: Thanks to ans me but i ask what is the reason for it must be a non zero.